# Change the visibility of a panel (Windows Forms)

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms-designer

I leave it to you because I can't find a solution to my problem : /

Let me explain, when I press a button I display a panel containing other buttons, at the click of one of the buttons on the panel it should launch a method that will convert the selected files to pdf. As soon as the user has clicked on one of the buttons and confirmed the choice of file, I make my panel invisible and I then launch the conversion method.

The problem is that my panel disappears let's say by half (not entirely) because it launches the conversion method as quickly. I told myself that I was going to go through a secondary thread, however I cannot modify graphic elements on the second thread.

There is my code :

```
 Private Sub PBFolder_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PBFolder.Click
    Try
        Insert2Db("Debut de la fonction BTransforme_Click " + Environment.UserName.ToString, 1, 0, "ConvertFiles2PDF")
        'Log("Debut de la fonction BTransforme_Click")
        Dim OFD As New FolderBrowserDialog
        If OFD.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

            PanFileFolder.Visible = False

            ConvertFileFolder(False, OFD.SelectedPath.ToString)

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        'Log("Error " + ex.Message)
        Insert2Db("Error " + ex.Message + "User : " + Environment.UserName.ToString, 0, 3, "ConvertFiles2PDF")
    Finally
        Insert2Db("function BTransforme_Click Terminé " + Environment.UserName.ToString, 1, 0, "ConvertFiles2PDF")
        'Log("function BTransforme_Click Terminé")
    End Try
    LAppOne.Visible = True
    GifLoad.Visible = False
    Button1.Enabled = True
    BLog.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

As you can see I hide my panel thanks to line: **PanFileFolder.Visible = False** then I launch my conversion method **convertFileFolder (False, OFD.SelectedPath.ToString)**

I have put 2 images to illustrate my problem.
the 1st image shows you the panel that appears on click:
[image: After launch method]

the second image shows you the problem that this causes me to choose the folder:
[image: Problem panel visible]

When it has finished converting the files, the panel disappears correctly at this time.
Do you have an idea to solve this problem thank you in advance ;)

Comment: Maybe `Refresh() ` what's behind it before calling that method. Or `BeginInvoke()` the method. Or make that method `async` (it looks like it's possible). Btw, you should dispose of that `FolderBrowserDialog`.

Comment: Thank's the refresh perform correctly ! :D

Comment: The "refresh" is hiding the underlying problem...

Answer (score 0):

> I told myself that I was going to go through a secondary thread,
> however I cannot modify graphic elements on the second thread.

That is exactly what will fix your problem; `ConvertFileFolder()` needs to be running in a different thread so that GUI can refresh itself and be responsive to user interact.  You can update the GUI from that secondary thread using `Invoke()` calls.

Here I've added `Async` to the Button click handler, then we `Await` the `ConvertFileFolder()` FUNCTION, which now returns a `Task`:

```
Private Async Sub PBFolder_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PBFolder.Click

    ' ... other code ...

    Using OFD As New FolderBrowserDialog
        If OFD.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            PanFileFolder.Visible = False
            Await ConvertFileFolder(False, OFD.SelectedPath.ToString)
        End If
    End Using

    ' ... other code ...

End Sub

Public Function ConvertFileFolder(ByVal someFlag As Boolean, ByVal someString As String) As Task
    Return Task.Run(Sub()

                        ' ... long running code in here ...

                        For i As Integer = 1 To 10

                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000) ' some "work"

                            ' whenever you need to update the GUI, use Invoke()
                            Dim value As String = i.ToString
                            Me.Invoke(Sub()

                                          Label1.Text = value

                                      End Sub)

                        Next

                    End Sub)
End Function
```